# Django Http404 message not showing up

Tags: python, django

I am currently on Django documentation part 3 where I have to create the polls app. However, when I make a request to the url having path like http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/, I was supposed to get the message 'Question does not exist.' But I don't.

Here is my code

polls/views.py

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound, Http404
 from django.shortcuts import render

 from .models import Question
 # Create your views here.


 def index(request):
     # - sign to get more recent, list is ordered from 0 to 4
     latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
     context = {
         'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
     }
     return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


 def detail(request, question_id):
     try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
     except Question.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Question does not exist")
     return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


 def results(request, question_id):
     response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
     return HttpResponse(response % question_id)


 def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [

    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

The error is

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/
Raised by:  polls.views.detail
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/ [name='index']
polls/ <int:question_id>/ [name='detail']
The current path, polls/3/, matched the last one.
```

Comment: Did you create the template file as mentioned in the documentation? `polls/templates/polls/detail.html`

Comment: @Dil, yes I did. It shows me correct questions when I put id=1 and id=2. I have only 2 questions

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `raise Http404("Question does not exist")` to `return HttpResponseNotFound("Question does not exist")`

You can set `debug=false` , provide a message to Http404 and then it will appear in the standard 404 debug template. Find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).

Comment: I get this error  UnboundLocalError at /polls/3/
local variable 'question' referenced before assignment

Comment: it is in views btw

Comment: I guess you forgot the **return** in `return HttpResponseNotFound("Question does not exist")`

Comment: oh yes. It is working with HttpResponseNotFound but I want to do it with Http404 :(((

Comment: @ox1234567 On Django development environment you can't show customised error pages. You can set 'debug=false' , provide a message to Http404 and then it will appear in the standard 404 debug template. Find more details [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231111/discussion-between-ox1234567-and-dil).